# Multiple spring boot project with Selenium

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, maven, multi-module

I'm currently working on setting up Selenium to my project in Spring boot. I currently have the project separated in two modules, front-end and back-end but working on merging the project to one module with Strangler Fig Pattern.

My question about Selenium is that if it's possible to run both the project with selenium?
I'm thinking of a structure of something like this.

```
root
|--- src/test (selenium tests)
|
|--- frontend
   |
   |--- pom.xml
|
|--- backend
   |
   |--- pom.xml
```

The frontend is very depended on the backend project to be able to even use the web page.

Is this strategy good as a temporary solution for when incremental strangler fig pattern strategy or should I be doing something else?

This project was handed to me with out any test and I'm working on implementing a structure for the testing. Found that having multiple modules for a small project was not necessary and should instead be merged together.

Comment: Selenium tests are browser tests. It doesn't matter where they are because they have nothing to do with the code

Comment: the file structure seems ok. Albeit it might be better to break that into 3 repos to be more independent.